# Having my UIView go from one video to the next

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer

I'm kinda new at this, Ive successfully embedded a video into a UIView. Got it to play automatically, without any controls. So far so good.

Now I want to be able to play the next video, and ideally the user can swipe and the next video will start playing... here's the code I have now;

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
var player: AVPlayer!
var avpController = AVPlayerViewController()


override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
   let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jordanreel", ofType: "mp4")
          let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)

    player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)


    avpController.player = player

    avpController.view.frame.size.height = videoView.frame.size.height

    avpController.view.frame.size.width = videoView.frame.size.width

    avpController.showsPlaybackControls = false

    avpController.player?.play()

    self.videoView.addSubview(avpController.view)   }
```

}

Comment: so What the question? can u please explain properly

Comment: how do I have my av player play more than video?